# Цитирование и правильность выполнения

Tags: цитирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ: 3, 4 .....................................

Comment: Вы правильно поняли задание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, ответ верный.

В 3-м предложении цитата должна быть встроена по принципу **косвенной речи** (двоеточие не нужно):

*А. Толстой считал, **что** «русский язык должен стать мировым языком».*

В 4-м предложении перед цитатой находится **вводное предложение** (вместо двоеточия нужна запятая):

***Как писал П. Мериме***, «русский язык — язык, созданный для поэзии, он необычайно богат и примечателен главным образом тонкостью оттенков».

[**Способы передачи чужой речи**](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/311-sposobyperedachichugoyrechi.html)